# How to hide keyboard in android

Tags: android

I wants to hide keyboard of device. I have try this code but its not working for me, Please Suggest me some other codes.

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 if (imm != null) {
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
 }
```

I have also try for manifest file but its also not working

Answer (score 1):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When this code in root view's onTouch, it should work. If you want to hide keyboard when activity opened, you can add [`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

use this code using inputmanager and hideSoftInputFromWindow

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add LinearLayout(with visibility gone/invisible) or any layout,that has no child.
And redirect the focus to it when activity starts.

;)